# Dual DNS Issue - Internal & External

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, internal-dns, dns-zone, dns-hosting

I'm in a fix here in offering a softphone solution for a company to allow users work from home.

CURRENT SCENARIO:

The company has an existing internal Windows DNS "ABCcompany.com" and externally they have another DNS "XYZcompany.com".

The softphone installed in the Smartphones is configured to speak to telephony server "softphone.XYZcompany.com" which can be reached from a public network (public wifi or 4G/5G). The problem is when these users are working internally from their company network, the softphone cannot register internally to the server since it has another DNS "ABCcompany.com" as "XYZcompany.com" does not exist internally.

I wanted to know if there is a way that we can add another DNS record  "smartphone.XYZcompany.com" pointing to a specific internal IP of the server? Keeping in mind that their internal DNS is "ABCcompany.com".

Comment: Why not use IPs instead of names internally when connecting via outside VPN ?

Comment: Why use stubborn IPs when you can have the flexibility of DNS?

Answer (score 2):

Create an internal DNS zone named smartphone.XYZcompany.com and create a "Same as parent folder" A record for the internal ip address of the server.

[image]

[image]

[image]